# install software with logon.bat script

Tags: domain-controller, batch-file, windows-sbs-2011

On an SBS2011 server I can see in AD that users have logon.bat in the Log In Scripts field of their profiles, but when I search the hard drive of the server I can't find logon.bat.

Firstly, I assume I just need to create it.  Where do I store it so it will work?

Secondly, I am going to use `msiexec /i \\ipaddress\ClickOneLegal\3.2.5.1003\PracticeEvolveClientSetup.msi /qn` to install our practice management software, but how can I also install Microsoft .NET Framework 4 silently?

Thirdly, how can I make the script detect if these softwares are already installed and not proceed if this is the case?

Comment: 1) Check \\servername\NETLOGON share for the logon.bat file. 2) You should look into a GPO to do the Software Install for you.  3) Same for .NET framework (or use WSUS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep in mind, that if you want to install software, which requires admin rights, you cannot execute it from user logon script, because it will be executed under the user credentials. check for example this [forum at Microsoft TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/81dcc090-412d-4a7c-abc4-ab674f4054df/gpo-startup-and-logon-script-permissions-levels?forum=winserverGP).

I would recommend you to use Group Policy and configure startup scripts, which are executed at computer startup.

Comment: implemented a GPO.  It was just hard to work out in SBS 2011